# I am unable to make the thing do what I want to using KeyEventArgs

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am a noob at this so try not to be angry if the answer is evident. The problem is when i try to use the Enter button to move the text in TextBox1, it does not, I get no errors but it does not work

```
Private Sub Send(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then

        Label1.Text = ""
        Label1.Text = Label2.Text
        Label2.Text = Label3.Text
        Label3.Text = Label4.Text
        Label4.Text = TextBox1.Text
        TextBox1.ResetText()
    End If
End Sub
```

I wanted it to be able to move the text from TextBox1 to Label4 but it does not.

Comment: Are you sure it is going into the `If` statement?

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point and seen if the debugger enters your metod?

Comment: Have you disabled the Form's KeyPreview (if appropriate)?

Comment: The Enter, Escape, Tab and cursor keys are used for navigation.  Operating the default buttons of a window (OK and Cancel) and moving the focus.  They therefore don't trigger the KeyDown event.  Override ProcessCmdKey() to see them.  Do avoid making your UI work like a console mode app, it is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Form's [KeyPreview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview?view=netframework-4.7.2) - set it to False - otherwise the Form will absorb the Enter key and just move between controls.

Comment: It would be the exact opposite: without `KeyPreview` set to true, the Form (`MyBase.KeyDown`) will never raise the `KeyDown` event. It will be handled only by the TextBox. Also, if there is a Button on the Form and it has the focus, the event won't be raised anyway.

Comment: The only way to be sure to get the key press in any case, is what Hans Passant wrote about in the comments.